# UISearchBar within UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar

I am trying to add a search bar programmatically to an UIView (not a UITableView). For the moment, I am just trying to set the delegates properly so that when I click the "enter" button, a message is printed:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"enter button clicked");
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I already have some code working for an `UITableViewController` that I am trying to adapt. It looks like this (I am skipping all the parts of the code that are not relevant to the present discussion):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableViewController *resultsTableController;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.resultsTableController = [[SearchResultsController alloc] init];
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultsTableController];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
}
```

Now the only line that doesn't transpose to the `UIViewController` case is the last one

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

My `UIViewController` is defined with a xib which contains a `UIView` called `myView`  and a `UISearchBar` called `searchBar`. So I tried doing

```
self.myView = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

or

```
self.searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

but in the first case the `searchBar`doesn't even show and in the second case the delegation to `self` seems lost (nothing happens when I click enter).

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would add a UISearchBar to a UIViewController programmatically:

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, kScreenWidth, 40.0)];
self.searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
self.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
self.searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.searchBar.tintColor = kRunnerSearchBarTintColor;

if ([RunnerUtilities isIOS7orAbove]) {
    self.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleProminent;
    [self.searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:185.0/255.0 green:195.0/255.0 blue:202.2/255.0 alpha:0]];
}

self.searchBar.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
```

Well, this is no more different than adding it from XIB file. First, search bar is a added as a subview to view of view controller and should be connected to search bar outlet defined in ViewController. Second, UIViewController must be set as delegate of the search bar. Please ensure you are following this and this should work.

**EDIT::**

If you are trying to use UISearchController within UIViewController, please try with following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{        
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any custom init from here...

    // Create a UITableViewController to present search results since the actual view controller is not a subclass of UITableViewController in this case
    UITableViewController *searchResultsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];

    // Init UISearchController with the search results controller
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];

    // Link the search controller
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;

    // This is obviously needed because the search bar will be contained in the navigation bar
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

    // Required (?) to set place a search bar in a navigation bar
    self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;

    // This is where you set the search bar in the navigation bar, instead of using table view's header ...
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;

    // To ensure search results controller is presented in the current view controller
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

    // Setting delegates and other stuff
    searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource = self;
    searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;        
}
```

Comment: If I do `self.searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar` and `self.searchBar.delegate = self` it doesn't work; if I just do `self.searchBar.delegate = self` (without the first instruction) it does. What do you think ?

Comment: My problem being that I want to use the searchBar of my searchController

Comment: Please see my updated response. Main point is set your search controller' search bar as title view of controller' navigationItem.

Comment: Thanks, but can't I place the search bar in another place than the titleView ? I would like to have it in some particular place of my view (defined through the xib).

Comment: ^figure this out?  I'm trying to do the same.

Comment: @vib did you figure it out? I am having the same issue as you where I need to have it

Comment: self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;
This is exactly what I'm looking for. @Abhinav